# How to bind a child component into parent based on environment property?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to bind a child component into a parent based on an if statement form environment file :

**parent.component.html**:

```
<form>
   ...
   <app-address *ngIf="userAddress"... #inputUserAddress></app-child>
   ...
   <button (click)="addUserAttribute( inputUserAddress.value )"></button>
</form>
```

**parent.component.ts**:

```
public userAddress = environment.formFields.address;
```

**environment.prod.ts**:

```
formFields{ address: true}
```

When I run `ng serve --prod`, it looks like the child component has not been bound into parent. Error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'

If I remove the `*ngIf` and just embed the child directly, then it works straight forward.

Where am I going wrong? Would this kind of concept work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill this property in your environment.prod.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an ElementRef type.

https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Change the HTML to this:

```
<button (click)="addUserAttribute( inputUserAddress.nativeElement.value )"></button>
```

Comment: `inputUserAddress.nativeElement.value` not to use in the view. Just in TS file.